# Excel file not closing

Tags: excel, xlsxwriter

I am using XlsxWriter to create an Excel files using a Python script.  When I run the script to update the file with new information, which I need to do often, the last file in the list remains open and excel throws me error that the "file is still open in python"

This is my code:

```
try:
    filter = filter.upper()
except:
    filter = filter
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Outputs/Capacitis&Shortfall_' + filter + '.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
information.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Capacities & Shortfalls', index = False)

workbook = writer.book
writer.save()
workbook.close()
```